# if statement with multiple or conditions returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am pretty sure I am missing something basic here but I am having trouble with using multiple `or` or `||` operators with my if statement.

For some reason the if statement is not catching the name variable:

```
testword = "billy"

if ((testword != "billy") ||
    (testword != "tom") ||
    (testword != "sara") ||
    (testword != "michael")) {
console.log("none of the names match")
} else {
console.log("name found!")
}
```

When I try this I get `none of the names match` when I should get `name found!`

Comment: its a common mistake. you need to think step by step. the first one will return false. the second one will return true. if the word ist `tom` it will return `true` in first condition and `false` in second. You nee the `&&` operator here instead of `||`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a bit convoluted

A far simpler approach to both write and understand is put all those names in an array and see if the array includes the testword. This is only a single boolean test

```js
const testword = "billy",
  words = ["billy", "tom", "sara", "michael"]

if (words.includes(testword)) {
  console.log("name found!")
} else {
  console.log("none of the names match")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operators execute to true when any of the condition is not equal to `testword` thus logging `none of the names match`

However, you can try to change your code to

```
testword = "billy"
names = ['billy','tom','sara','michael',]

if (names.indexOf(testword) != -1) {
console.log("name found!")
} else {
console.log("none of the names match")
}
```